# WITH Clause use UNION ALL in ORACLE 11G

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, with-statement

Can you please give me alternate query for the below code.

PLSQL Code

I have used WITH Clause variable TEMP is used two place in UNION ALL query, help to reduce only one time to use TEMP variable in UNION ALL query,

```
DECLARE

  CURSOR CUR Is  
    WITH TEMP AS    
     (SELECT 1 ONE FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 2 ONE FROM DUAL)   
    SELECT RNO, NAME  FROM STUDENT, TEMP T  WHERE RNO = T.ONE   
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT RNO, NAME FROM STUDENT1, TEMP T WHERE RNO = T.ONE;   
BEGIN

  FOR I IN CUR LOOP  
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I.RNO||':'||i.name);   
  END LOOP;

END;
```

Table Creation scripts

```
create table student1(rno number,name varchar2(30))    

insert into student1 values(1,'chidam1')    
insert into student1 values(2,'ram1')    
insert into student1 values(3,'divi1')

create table student(rno number,name varchar2(30))

insert into student values(1,'chidam')
insert into student values(2,'ram')
insert into student values(3,'divi')
```

Comment: We can see what your code does: you need to explain its purpose. We cannot offer an alternative implementation until you tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Just like multiplication is distributive over addition in algebra, and Cartesian product is distributive over union in set theory, so `INNER JOIN` is distributive over `UNION ALL` in SQL.

You could rewrite your `SELECT` statement like so:

```
with
     temp          as ( ... - your definition here     )
   , student_union as ( select rno, name from student 
                        UNION ALL
                        select rno, name from student1 )
select s.rno, s.name from student_union s inner join temp t on s.rno = t.one
........................
```

A few notes... use ANSI join syntax (SQL Standard) whenever possible, do not use the old, deprecated Oracle syntax. Also, use qualifiers (table aliases) for all columns in a join, even if they are not always strictly necessary; the code is much easier to read that way.